# Can the board of a company gamble on bitcoins without the consent of the shareholders?

Tags: united-states, civil-law

Can the board of a company invest in bitcoins without the consent of the shareholders? Is it allowed in privately owned companies as well as publically traded  companies and in what situations can the shareholders sue the company for it? I see people suing company for losing money in stocks, so I am wondering if it applies here.

Assume the country is the United States.

Comment: Do you mean literally gamble, where gambling itself is illegal? Or do you mean "invest", where it is possible to lose money.

Comment: Investing in crypto is gambling.

Comment: So it's against the law, right?

Comment: How do you know?

Comment: If such investments / "gambles" are allowed by federal and state law as well as the company's charter and bylaws, why shouldn't this be legal?  Is there a particular law you think would be violated?

Comment: They need to act in the best interest of the shareholders.

Comment: Try to avoid using legal terms colloquially, even if it's to make a point. There is a legal definition of gambling which does not include investment in crypto- insisting on referring to it as gambling when it isn't makes your question unclear and suggests you want to hear a certain answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A privately held company can generally pursue any lawful business activity unless it has led its private investors to believe otherwise with its representations.

A publicly held company (i.e. one with shares or bonds traded on a securities exchange, or otherwise marketed to the general public, or having more than 500 investors and more than a certain amount of capital), must essentially disclose to its investors all foreseeable material risks associated with the investment, including the risk of losses in cryptocurrency if it makes material investments in it. Shareholder consent wouldn't be required, but disclosure of this potential investment activity to shareholders (allowing shareholders who are displeased to sell shares in the company to avoid the risk) is required in publicly held companies.

Comment: BitCoin is effectively a currency, and a company could also have obligations in BTC. Those too would require disclosing, as they could carry the inverse exchange risk. This shows the exact details don't matter; it's fact that a risk exists which needs to be reported.

Comment: @MSalters "it's fact that a risk exists which needs to be reported." Absolutely, so long as the risk if material. If you have $100K USD worth of bitcoin in a company with $2B of cash on hand, you wouldn't need to disclose it. If you had a lot of it, though, or were in transactions that could cause you to have a lot of it, it would need to be disclosed.

Answer (score 3):

### A company can buy, sell and hold cryptocurrency

Just like they can buy, sell or hold: land, motor vehicles, other companies, mineral rights, pork futures, stationary, computers, office furniture etc.

The obligation on directors to serve the interests of the comply is subject to the “business judgement” rule. That is, they can operate the business and make decisions and not be liable if those decisions turn out bad with the benefit of hindsight.

If there is a legitimate business reason for a business to buy, sell or hold cryptocurrency then that’s what they should do. Legitimate reasons would be if they need to buy or sell goods and services denominated in crypto or if the business actually exists in order to invest in crypto.